# Phalcon - add OR criteria to find()

Tags: php, phalcon

hope someone can help.

I am using the find()  as follows

```
$query = Criteria::fromInput($this->di, 'Models\Templates', $this->request->getPost());
$this->persistent->searchParams = $query->getParams();
$parameters = $this->persistent->searchParams;
$templates= templates::find(
        $parameters,
        );
```

This gives me the resulting set of templates based on the parameters posted.

What I want to be able to do is add to these parameters an OR somehow.

i.e find all the templates which have the criteria as per the post, OR ones which have the field "global" set to Y

I was going to run a second query to get the global templates and concatenate the results set, but surely there must be some way to add an OR to the criteria?

Any help would be really gratefully received!

Martin

Comment: I have found it.  As I am using Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Criteria then I can add to it before making the query.  All I needed to do is add:   $query->orWhere("global = 'Y'");

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = Criteria::fromInput($this->di, 'Models\Templates', $this->request->getPost());

//added this below to add the additional or query to the Criteria builder

$query->orWhere("global = 'Y'");

$this->persistent->searchParams = $query->getParams();
parameters = $this->persistent->searchParams;
$templates= templates::find(
    $parameters,
    );
```